# AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.util' has no attribute 'deprecated_params'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am getting that error when trying to import SQLAlchemy from flask_sqlalchemy:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

The complete error message is:

```
  File "C:\Users\..\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 63, in Pool
@util.deprecated_params(
AttributeError: module 'sqlalchemy.util' has no attribute 'deprecated_params'
```

The version of my libraries are sqlalchemy = 1.1.13 and flask_sqlalchemy = 2.4.0

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to update both of them?

Comment: Thanks! that worked.. I was assuming I had the latest versions because running pip install would output that the 'requirement is already satisfied'. But after your suggestion I investigated and realized that pip install does not update the library if not explicitly requested. I updated and the issue disappeared.

Comment: Same error here, most recent stable releases as per Pypi for today:
`pip freeze | grep chemy`
`Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0`
`SQLAlchemy==1.3.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same error with my python env which is managed via [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv).

I ran `pipenv update sqlalchemy` which strangely enough rolled back sqlalchemy's version to 1.2.19 from what I [had before, which was 1.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341112/attributeerror-module-sqlalchemy-util-has-no-attribute-deprecated-params#comment100085249_56341112).

```sh
pip freeze | grep chemy
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.19
```

This now works for me without error:
`python -c "from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy"`

I guess that without pipenv, one can manually use pip to re-install sqlalchemy for this specific version.